# How to validate dates with time zone?

Tags: java, datetime-format, dateformatter

I want to use the following ISO 8601 Format(Date and time with timezone) :
`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

To verify if the string date is valid or not.

I have as input a String date

```
String dateRight = "2017-12-25T13:01:59.123-0700"
String date2Right = "2017-12-25T13:01:59.123Z"
```

I want to check if these dates are in the right format that I mentioned above.

So far, I tried to use ZoneDateTime, LocalDateTime, DateTimeFormatter but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose the *java.time* class appropriate to your input string.
2. Attempt to parse using the `parse` method.
3. Trap for `DateTimeParseException`.

The exception is thrown (a) if the inout text is malformed or (b) if its contents are nonsensical such as day of month being 32.

For your second example input, use `Instant`. That class represents a moment as seen in UTC. The `Z` on the end of your input means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Pronounced “Zulu”.

If your input text complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, then no need to define a formatting pattern.

```
try {
    Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2017-12-25T13:01:59.123Z" ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    …
}
```

For your first example string, use `OffsetDateTime`. Your offset omitted the COLON character delimiter between the hours and minutes of the offset. So you’ll need to define a formatting pattern using `DateTimeFormatter` class. Search Stack Overflow, as this has been covered many times already.

Use `ZonedDateTime` if the input contains a date, time, and a time zone in the format of `Continent/Region` such as `Asia/Tokyo` Or `Africa/Casablanca`.

The `ZonedDateTime` class will attempt a guess at a 2-4 character pseudo-zone, but those are not standardized and are not even unique! Values such as `CST` and `IST` should only be used in localization for presentation, never for data exchange.